# Dart / Flutter decrypting with Public Key

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, rsa, public-key

I have created a RSA key pair at my server and **only** the server will have the private key. The clients (flutter app) are going to have access to the public key. Therefore when the server receives an encrypted message it will know that message is coming from proper client and will decrypt the message, which was encrypted via public key, with it's private key.

When the server (php 7.3) sends a reply to the client I would like encrypt the message via private key at the server side so that the client could decrypt the message with the public key.

Asymmetric encryption has it's own limitations such as max character lenght. But it would be nice to send & receive small messages.

Flutter packages encrypt & pointycastle doesn't seem to support decrypting with Public Key. I don't want the clients to have the both keys.

Probably I will have to utilize symmetric encryption. But I would be greatful if you could advise a solution.

Note: I have been able to encrypt a message with public key via pointycastle but it is very complicated for me to write a function that decrypts data with the public key.

Comment: Do you understand that in your scheme anybody with the public key can decrypt, and thus you get no security at all?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a RSA key pair at my server and only the server will have the private key. The clients (flutter app) are going to have access to the public key. Therefore when the server receives an encrypted message it will know that message is coming from proper client and will decrypt the message, which was encrypted via public key, with it's private key.

Generally we try and not put any security on the public key. If you want to authenticate your messages you should use client specific key pairs and generate signatures with them.

Furthermore, generally you don't just want to keep messages confidential, you want to make sure they haven't been tampered with either (integrity that comes with the message authenticity).

> When the server (php 7.3) sends a reply to the client I would like encrypt the message via private key at the server side so that the client could decrypt the message with the public key.

You would do that with a public key that belongs to a client's key pair.

> Asymmetric encryption has it's own limitations such as max character lenght. But it would be nice to send & receive small messages.

Max bit or rather byte size, not character length. But generally we'd use hybrid encryption anyway.

> Flutter packages encrypt & pointycastle doesn't seem to support decrypting with Public Key. I don't want the clients to have the both keys.

This is good, because decryption with a public key doesn't make sense, you'd use separate key pairs.

> Probably I will have to utilize symmetric encryption. But I would be greatful if you could advise a solution.

Preferably you would just use TLS, and use TLS with client authentication for simple transport security.

If you need application level security then you could use a container format such as CMS instead. Preferably you'd use two key pairs per entity: one for encryption (towards the holder of the private key) and one for signature generation by the holder of the private key (i.e. message integrity & authenticity).

> Note: I have been able to encrypt a message with public key via pointycastle but it is very complicated for me to write a function that decrypts data with the public key.

Good. Don't.

Comment: Too long for a comment. I would have flagged for migration as this is not yet really about programming, more [security.se], but I don't think it would be accepted there.

Comment: Could you please advise where should I store the private key of the client?

Comment: Within the app / client. You also need a way to establish trust within the public key though. You could use the same key pair for each client, but in that case you would not be able to authenticate clients separately, and loss of one private key would mean loss of all authenticity and confidentiality.